# simple logarithms with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Note: I am using log base 10 and I am trying to rewrite the equation using exponents instead of logs.

Here is what I have and I am wondering if I did it correctly (if not how am I suspose to solve this question):

$$\log(A^2) = B$$
$$2\log(A) = \log(B)$$
$$\log(B)/\log(A) = 2$$
$$10^2$$

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does the out of the blue $10^2$ mean? Are you trying to find $A$ in terms of $B$? Or something else?

Comment: Are you trying to solve explicitly for $A$ and $B$? Also, from the first line to the second, you make a mistake. The $\log(B)$ should only be $B$.

Comment: The instructions are: Rewrite each of the following using exponents instead of logs. The question is Log(A^2)=B.

About the 10^2 I got that because for example log(0.01) <=> 10^-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line doesn't look correct. The rule is $\log(A^n)=n\cdot\log(A)$, so:

$$
\log(A^2)=B \\
2\log(A)=B \\
\log(A)=\frac{1}{2}B \\
A=10^{\frac{1}{2}B}
$$

Comment: I've removed my down vote. Your solution looks correct now.

Comment: Thank you - just a silly mistake!